# Grails with Postgresql : can't create table in appropriate schema

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I want to use **Grails 3.3.0** with a **Postgresql database** and also with three schema : openlearning, data and contrib.
In domain classes, I specified the schema I want (see below).
My issue is that tables are created only in public schema and not in the appropriate schema.

How can I do to create tables in the correct schema ?

**note :** Tables are all created in public schema.The other schema are created but are empty.They doesn't contain any table.

*Question Domain class :*

```
package fr.dr.openlearning
class Question {

 static mapping = {
 id generator: 'increment',params:[sequence:'incr']
 schema : "data"
}
```

*application.yml :*

```
dataSource:
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openlearning
  username: postgres
  password: XXX
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true


environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
        dataSources:
            data:
              dbCreate: create-drop
            contrib:
              dbCreate: create-drop
```

Answer (score 1):

In your application.yml file change the dbCreate: create-drop to
 **dbCreate: create**.

Comment: Thanks to the answer but it is the same.Table are only create in public schema.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a new schema in your database as Super Admin
2. Change your username and password as your new schema in `application.yml`
3. Change your `dbCreate: create-drop` to `dbCreate: update`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test it and I answer you later